# How to setup Wordpress Pretty Permalink on shared IIS7 hosting with no url rewrite module installed

Tags: wordpress, iis-7, shared-hosting, permalinks

I have setup Wordpress blog v2.9.2 on my website at location www.22shruti.com/blog/ (Shared IIS 7.0 Hosting (no admin rights on the server), PHP 5.2.13 FastCGI, WHB Operating System 2008, no url rewrite module installed.)

Since pretty permalinks are useful from SEO perspective, when I try to change the WP Permalink setting to a custom "/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/" via admin, I get following message on www.22shruti.com/blog/

"Not Found Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."

What is the step by step solution to achieve the desired permalink format in this scenario? Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think you would find the answer here - [How To Set Pretty Permalinks in Wordpress Runs On IIS 7](http://www.geekblogger.org/2010/03/how-to-set-pretty-permalinks-in.html) I guess you need to put one web.config file in the root folder like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <remove value="index.php" />
    <add value="index.php" />
  </files>
 </defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
 <rules>
     <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```